# sqlite3_analyzer not working in Ubuntu missing shared object file

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, sqlite

I am learning more about sqlite3 and am trying to use the sqlite3_analyzer to view a bunch of data about my data. The problem is when I download the sqlite-analyzer-linux-x86-3071502.zip from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and unzip this package and THEN try to run the program I receive THIS error: `./sqlite3_analyzer: error while loading shared libraries: libtcl8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know where to get this libtcl8.6.so file? Does anyone know how to install this after obtaining it?

Answer (score 3):

Install the package `tcl8.6`, or download the analyzer source code and recompile it with the Tcl version in your distribution.

Comment: cool. how do these things though...? Do you have a link to a tutorial kind sir?

Comment: does installing this binary from here: http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads work?

Comment: well the Linux x86 software installs, but does not uninstall and the x86_64 appears to have the .so i need but does not install! :/

Comment: Posting links to the `tcl8.6` package or repos where it can be retrieved would be appreciated

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tcl8.6)

Comment: @CL. Yeah but these are only for raring and saucy. I have 12.04 LTS (precise)

Comment: "sudo apt-get install libtcl8.6:i386" solved the problem for me (14.04/trusty)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading an older version of sqlite3_analyzer from a third party website (do a search for `sqlite-analyzer-linux-x86`) that worked without the dependency. I won't post links as I can't ensure that they'll be available and serve the same file as I downloaded.

If you decide to do that, be sure to check the file for viruses on http://virustotal.com! Can't trust these Chinese file hostings ;)

Comment: Cool, I will have to check this out. More importantly this probably also helps other SQLite Ubuntu users. :D Thank-you @Dmitry Pashkevich :)